# C++ Extract substring and convert to specific date format

Tags: c++, regex, date, date-formatting

I have a bunch of dates that I want to convert into YYYYMMDD format via C++. I currently have the following code which just runs it through the linux date command:

```
      string shell_arg = inputStr;
      shell_arg = "'" + shell_arg + "'";
      string cmd="date -d " + shell_arg +  " +%Y%m%d 2>/dev/null";

      FILE *ls = popen(cmd.c_str(), "r");
      char retval[100];
      fgets(retval, sizeof(retval), ls);

      pclose(ls);

      if(!isdigit(retval[0]))
      {   
          strcpy(retval,"99991231");
      }

      return retval;
```

This handles most date formats, and ones that can't be handled return "99991231". I have a number of dates of format like

```
"Sep- 13"
"12 -Oct"
"13-Nov"
```

That are supposed to evaluate to the first of the month for each year, like

```
20130901
20121001
20131101
```

Respectively. How would you do accomplish this? I should note, if we are going to use regex, my configuration can only use the GNU C library (which uses regexec and regcomp, as opposed to regex_match).

Comment: Why do you use **both** a character array and `std::string`?

Comment: split with the -, trim both strings, detect for which `atoi(s.data())` doesn't return `0` and swap it if needed with the other one, then use the first one as the year and the second one as the month?

Comment: This would work once I determine it is of the right format. Any thoughts on how to do that? @coyotte508

Comment: Check if there's a '-' inside the string? Without a list of all the different format possible it's hard to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since your input can be in multiple formats, I suggest a simple state machine.  The state machine will allow you to back up and retry a different pattern.

Use `std::getline` to read the date into a `std::string` type.

You can use `std::istringstream` to parse the data.